# How do I correctly addClass to an element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a nav, each li item containing their own specific class. I want the nav li item to be "active" while the user is on the current page, by adding an "active" class to the current li item. But it's not working and Im not sure why. This could be a stupid mistake so please forgive me

Here's what I have:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.intro-page').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: can you give us your html code?

Comment: That looks reasonable, as far as it goes. Any errors in the [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: If that element exists, the class will be added (assuming no script errors in console). Are you sure it's not being added and your css just isn't specific enough? Easy enough to inspect within live html in browser dev tools. Show associated html

Comment: Try to put `active` class on its `li` tag

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is adding the active class the the `<a>` element. It sounds like you want to add it to the `<li>` tag that the link is in instead?

If that's the case, something like this would work:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.intro-page').parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```